# What is right requirement to create Model Classes in my iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, alamofire, swifty-json

I am using [SwiftJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) to parse my data which I receive after making [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) call. API gives me event list like following

```
[

    {
        "eventData": "someDate",
        "eventTitle": "someTitle",
        .
        .
        so on
    }

    {
        "eventData": "someDate",
        "eventTitle": "someTitle",
        .
        .
        so on
    }

]
```

I will show this in TableView and will use the same data in some other ViewControllers. I don't see any need of creating an **Event** model class and do a mapping with JSON response. I can save the data as SwiftyJSON's JSON struct and use the same everywhere else. Is it a good software design approach ? What advantage will I get if have model classes of every data which is coming from API ?

Comment: I prefer using `ObjectMapper` by creating Model class instead of `SwiftyJSON`, as it gives more control over data. Rest depends upon your requirement.

Comment: Why use models? Because SwiftyJSON's JSON structs are slow, because JSON is for transport not for usage, because dictionaries are cumbersome, because models can behave in a custom way, because using model objects is how you code in Object Oriented Programming...

Answer (score 1):

A data model represents the structure of information in an app.

Reason

1. When you use a table view into your code then you need some information for   implementing the action on the table view click. here model class is hold that information.
2. If you are creating a model class in your application then the element of that model class may be reusable. let suppose you have two request and both are giving the same response, then you do not need to define any other variable to hold that value.
3. Easy to use and more flexible according to the requirement

Comment: All of this I can do If I store SwiftyJSON's JSON struct as part of my class. Or may be store that in Singleton. I can reuse it when I want.